# Join like in mongodb with arrays of documents and conditions

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I am struggling to create a MongoDB query to use aggregation in order to perform a join like a query with conditions.
This is my input :

'Things' collection :

```
{
    _id : 1
    users : [
        {
            userId : 00001,
            role : "creator"
        },
        {
            userId : 00002,
            role : "spectator"
        }
    ]
}
{
    _id : 2
    users : [
        {
            userId : 00002,
            role : "creator"
        },
        {
            userId : 00001,
            role : "spectator"
        }
    ]
}
```

'Users' Collection :

```
{
    _id : 00001,
    name : "John"
}
{
    _id : 00002,
    name : "Doe"
}
```

I want to get the creator's name/informations for a given 'Thing' _id and get something like this for _id = 1:

```
{
    _id : 00001,
    name : "John"
}
```

This is where I've been so far :

```
db.Things.aggregate([
    {
        $match:{
            _id:1
        }
    },
    {
        $lookup:{
            from:"Users",
            localField:"Users.userId",
            foreignField:"_id",
            as:"usersData"
        }
    },
    {
        $unwind : "$usersData"
    }
])
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: there is also `userId : 00002` in `_id = 1`, can you show your expected result.

Comment: `userId : 00002` in `_id = 1` does not have the role of `creator` but `spectator` in the 'users' array so he is not part of the expected result

Comment: it is possible if there are 2 matching uses from users array? if yes then how you want result, in a separate document or in same document.

Comment: It is not possible. Each `thing` has only one `creator` and it would be perfect if I can only have the creator name and `_id` but as long as I have the `name` it is ok

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- `$match` things `_id` and users `role` condition
- `$unwind` deconstruct `users` array
- `$match` `users` role condition
- `$lookup` with `users` collection
- `$arrayElemAt` to get first element from result of lookup
- `$replaceRoot` to replace above object to root

```
db.things.aggregate([
  { $match: { _id: 1, "users.role": "creator" } },
  { $unwind: "$users" },
  { $match: { "users.role": "creator" } },
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "Users",
      localField: "users.userId",
      foreignField: "_id",
      as: "users"
    }
  },
  {
    $replaceRoot: {
      newRoot: { $arrayElemAt: ["$users", 0] }
    }
  }
])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/xf69N_5DAci)

---

A second approach without using `$undind` stage,

- `$match` things `_id` and users `role` condition
- `$filter` to iterate loop of `uses` array and filter by `role` creator
- `$arrayElemAt` to select first element from above filtered result
- `$lookup` with `users` collection
- `$arrayElemAt` to get first element from result of lookup
- `$replaceRoot` to replace above object to root

```
db.things.aggregate([
  { $match: { _id: 1, "users.role": "creator" } },
  {
    $addFields: {
      users: {
        $arrayElemAt: [
          {
            $filter: {
              input: "$users",
              cond: { $eq: ["$$this.role", "creator"] }
            }
          },
          0
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "Users",
      localField: "users.userId",
      foreignField: "_id",
      as: "users"
    }
  },
  {
    $replaceRoot: {
      newRoot: { $arrayElemAt: ["$users", 0] }
    }
  }
])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/9zJl-5sAQCx)